# Using EnlighterJS in a React project

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, syntax-highlighting

I'm new to React and just wondering how I can get EnlighterJS syntax highlighter working in my React project.
I have downloaded the required files from EnlighterJS and updated my index.html file as below.

```html
...
<html>
<head>
  ...
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/assets/enlighterjs/enlighterjs.atomic.min.css" /> 
  ...
</head>
<body>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="%PUBLIC_URL%/assets/enlighterjs/enlighterjs.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    EnlighterJS.init('pre', 'code', {
      language: 'javascript',
      theme: 'atomic',
      indent: 2
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

However, nothing actually happens and there is no syntax highlighting whatsoever. I have double-checked the paths already. For context, I'm pulling the code from my WordPress blog (WordPress REST API).

I have also tried importing the enlighterjs.min.js file in my React component (shown below).

```html
import React from 'react';
import '../css/styles.css';
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';
import dgAPI from '../cms/DGAPI';
import { useFetch } from '../customhooks/useFetch';
import Loader from '../components/Loader';
import EnlighterJS from '../enlighterjs/enlighterjs.min';

const BlogPost = () => {
    let blogPostURL = dgAPI.getPostFromSlug + useParams().slug;
    const { loading, data } = useFetch(blogPostURL);
    const blogPost = data[0];

    return (
        <>
            {loading ? <Loader /> :
                <>
                    <div className='section-card'>
                        <div className="blog-post-header">
                            <h1 className='blog-post-title'>{blogPost.title.rendered}</h1>
                            <div className='author-container'>
                                <img src={`${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/assets/images/navbar/avatar-min.jpg`} alt='author' />
                                <div>
                                    <div className='author-name'>DG</div>
                                    <div className='publish-date'>{blogPost.formatted_date}</div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: blogPost.content.rendered }}></div>
                    </div>
                </>}
        </>
    )
}

export default BlogPost
```

After importing, I get the following errors.

```html
Failed to compile

src\enlighterjs\enlighterjs.min.js
  Line 2:546:    Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions
  Line 2:838:    Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions
  Line 2:4768:   Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions
  Line 2:5342:   Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions
  Line 2:5461:   Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions
  Line 2:6691:   Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions
  Line 2:21713:  Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions
  Line 2:35514:  Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions
  Line 2:46101:  Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions
  Line 2:47369:  Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions
  Line 2:49474:  Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions
  Line 2:49521:  Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions
  Line 2:49608:  Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions
  Line 2:49997:  Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions
  Line 2:50742:  Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions
  Line 2:50916:  Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions
  Line 2:51038:  Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions
  Line 2:51454:  Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions
  Line 2:53868:  Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions
  Line 2:56557:  Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions
  Line 2:57278:  Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions
  Line 2:57472:  Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions
  Line 3:1:      Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions

Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I figured it out.
EnlighterJS was in fact running. However, it was running BEFORE React was able to fetch the WordPress post (the code was inside the post) and render it, and as a result, the syntax was not being highlighted.

I used the useEffect hook to resolve this.

```html
    useEffect(() => {
        // Syntax Highlighting (EnlighterJS)
        let syntaxHighlightingScript = document.createElement('script');
        syntaxHighlightingScript.type = 'text/javascript';
        var code =
            `EnlighterJS.init('pre', 'code', {
                language: 'javascript',
                theme: 'atomic',
                indent: 2
            });`;
        try {
            syntaxHighlightingScript.appendChild(document.createTextNode(code));
            document.body.appendChild(syntaxHighlightingScript);
        } catch (e) {
            syntaxHighlightingScript.text = code;
            document.body.appendChild(syntaxHighlightingScript);
        }

        return function cleanup() {
            syntaxHighlightingScript.remove();
        }
    })
```

Now once the page has loaded (along with the code I want to highlight), a script element is created and appended to the document body. Once appended, the `EnlighterJS.init` function is called with the correct parameters.

Once the user clicks to go to another page, the `cleanup()` function is called to remove the appended script element.

Answer (score 0):

I will recommend this approach, where you have more control on when you want to initialize the library!

```
function AddLibrary(urlOfTheLibrary, onload) {
  const script = document.createElement('script');
  script.src = urlOfTheLibrary;
  script.onload = onload;
  script.async = true;
  document.body.appendChild(script);
}

function initEnlighterJS() {
    window.EnlighterJS.init('pre', 'code', {
      language: 'javascript',
      theme: 'enlighter',
      indent: 2,
    });
}


function App() {
    <div className="App">
      <pre>var j=0;</pre>

      { window.EnlighterJS
        ? initEnlighterJS()
        : AddLibrary('enlighterjs.min.js', function () {
            initEnlighterJS();
          })
      }
}
```